# Compile CMU PocketSphynx at Linux Mint 13

Tags: open-source, voice-recognition, cmusphinx, linux-mint

I've installed CMU Sphynx at Linux Mint 13 (based on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) and I simply cant' find any examples for:

1. How to just test how it work in most simple way? I want to launch it from command line and recognize any .wav file. I've read docs but there are just c++ or python examples, no examples for pocketsphynx_continious
2. Where can I get /dev/dsp devise at Mint? I have installed all dev libs for alsa and pulseaudio - no /dev/dsp at all.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recognize from microphone

```
pocketsphinx_continuous
```

To recognize a file (16khz mono 16bit)

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -infile file.wav
```

To create /dev/dsp you need to load kernel driver for oss

```
modprobe snd_pcm_oss
```

Development libs are for development, not for /dev/dsp. After you installed development libraries, you need to recompile and reinstall sphinxbase. It will detect development libraries and use alsa instead of oss.

Comment: Thank you, Nikolay! Your answers are very helpful for me. Right now I'm getting an error "FATAL_ERROR: "continuous.c", line 149: Failed to calibrate voice activity detection" when trying to recognize any wav file. File looks like right format (file out.wav: out.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 8000 Hz) I was trying 16k too - get the same error. Recognition from microphone works nice. I have no ideas what I can do to fix this bug )

Comment: File must be 16khz, not 8khz. For 8khz you need to add -samprate 8000 to the command line